# Is using groupby messing up my data values?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is the code I'm working with.

```
import pandas as pd

def GHCN(station_ID):
    '''This function reads GHCN Daily Data from Amazon Web Services given a GHCN station ID and calculates the 
       all time record high and low and the normal (mean) high and low temperature for the 1981-2010 period'''

    # Read the GHCN Daily Data
    df = pd.read_csv(
         "s3://noaa-ghcn-pds/csv/by_station/" + station_ID + ".csv",
         storage_options={"anon": True},  # passed to `s3fs.S3FileSystem`
         dtype={'Q_FLAG': 'object', 'M_FLAG': 'object'},
         parse_dates=['DATE']
     ).set_index('DATE')

    df_tmax = df.loc[df['ELEMENT'] == 'TMAX']
    df_tmin = df.loc[df['ELEMENT'] == 'TMIN']

    # Calculate the actual low temperature
    ser=df_tmin[~((df_tmin.index.month==2)&(df_tmin.index.day==29))]
    actual_tmin = (ser['DATA_VALUE']/10.).groupby(ser.index.day_of_year)

    # Calculate the actual high temperature
    ser=df_tmax[~((df_tmax.index.month==2)&(df_tmax.index.day==29))]
    actual_tmax = (ser['DATA_VALUE']/10.).groupby(ser.index.day_of_year)

    # Calculate the record low temperature
    ser=df_tmin[~((df_tmin.index.month==2)&(df_tmin.index.day==29))]
    record_tmin = (ser['DATA_VALUE']/10.).groupby(ser.index.day_of_year).min()

    # Calculate the record high temperature
    ser=df_tmax[~((df_tmax.index.month==2)&(df_tmax.index.day==29))]
    record_tmax = (ser['DATA_VALUE']/10.).groupby(ser.index.day_of_year).max()

    # Calculate the mean low temperature
    ser=df_tmin[~((df_tmin.index.month==2)&(df_tmin.index.day==29))]
    mean_tmin = (ser['DATA_VALUE']/10.).groupby(ser.index.day_of_year).mean()

    # Calculate the mean high temperature
    ser=df_tmax[~((df_tmax.index.month==2)&(df_tmax.index.day==29))]
    mean_tmax = (ser['DATA_VALUE']/10.).groupby(ser.index.day_of_year).mean()

    # Create pandas dataframe for temperature values
    temps = pd.DataFrame([[actual_tmin, mean_tmin, record_tmin, actual_tmax, mean_tmax, record_tmax]],
        columns= ['actual_min_temp', 'average_min_temp', 'record_min_temp', 'actual_max_temp', 'average_max_temp', 'record_max_temp'])
    
    return temps, actual_tmin, actual_tmax, record_tmin, record_tmax, mean_tmin, mean_tmax

GHCN('USW00094870')
```

It seems to be working fine, but once I call the function, it seems that the actual_tmin and actual_tmax are either in a different format or not there at all. I'll include a short example of the output here.

```
(                                     actual_min_temp  \
 0  <pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy obj...   
 
                                     average_min_temp  \
 0  DATE
 1     -8.076000
 2     -6.860000
 3     -7....
```

I'm new to coding so I don't exactly know if I'm asking this question correctly, but how can I get the actual_tmax and actual_tmin to look the same as the other calculated temperatures?

Comment: No. The df_tmax and df_tmin values divided by 10 and indexed for leap years are what actual_tmin and actual_tmax should be. I just didn't know if I needed to do something else since the other calculated temperatures will have dates as 1 through 365 and the df_tmin and df_tmax have dates formatted like 1997-06-01

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).